# Reset Content View in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, setcontentview

I have dialog, which includes a spinner in a constraintLayout ("new_widget_layout.xml"). To get the id of the Spinner I use this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.new_widget_layout)
val typeSpinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.widgetTypeSpinner)
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item).also {
            it.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            typeSpinner.adapter = it
        }
// The contentView is changed back, see below...
```

As you can see, I need to change the ContentView to my dialogLayout first, so I can get the id of the spinner. But if I want to change it back to the standard layout, my onclicklisteners don't work.

**Example**

```
val deleteButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.deleteButton) // This is before the contentView is changed

deleteButton.setOnClickListener { // This is after the content View is changed back and forth and it does nothing
            // code
        }
```

I tried multiple things to change the contentView back to normal, like:

- `setContentView(findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.myLayout))`
- `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

But nothing seems to work. All the buttons etc. show up correctly, but nothing happens, if they are clicked. It works, if I remove the code with the contentViews and the Spinner entirely.

Comment: Why do you need the spinner if you're just destroying the view straight afterwards anyway?

Comment: @HenryTwist Am I destroying it? I just need to get the spinner to add its contents. But I think I need to add these, when the layout is inflated. It seems to work.

Comment: If you're changing the content view to something else then the spinner won't exist? Sorry if I have missed the point.

Comment: i agree with @HenryTwist, i _honestly_ dont understand what you're trying to do here

Comment: I presume that `R.layout.activity_main` is your activity layout (very intuitive of me). So what does `R.id.new_widget_layout` represent exactly?

Comment: I am very new to that kind of stuff and i fixed the problem in a completely different way. Thank you for your comments/answers. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can restart the activity and use a condition like

```
if(Common.layoutType ==1)
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
else 
  setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
```

and in onClickListener you can store a value in common class (if not one kindly make it)

```
Public class Common
   {
     Public static int layoutType = 1;
    }
```

and in onClickListener

```
Common.layoutType = YOUR_DESIRED_VALUE;
startActivity(); /// again start the same activity
```

and when the activity will restart then during the check it will automatically set the desired layout accordingly.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**